# How count the frequency in categorical variables in python

Tags: python

I have a problem, I'm trying  count the frequency of categorical data:

If for example, I get:

[image]

I want to get

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Please replace any and all data- and code-examples with text, instead of images.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: What format does your data have? What have you tried so far with that data? We need some more information on that in order to properly help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using this example dataframe (minimal, but based on your images):

```
>>> df
    Data Visualization     Machine Learning           Statistics
0       Not Interested  Somewhat Interested      Very Interested
1       Not Interested       Not Interested  Somewhat Interested
2  Somewhat Interested       Not Interested      Very Interested
3  Somewhat Interested       Not Interested  Somewhat Interested
4      Very Interested      Very Interested       Not Interested
```

You can use `value_counts`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T


                    Not Interested  Somewhat Interested  Very Interested
Data Visualization               2                    2                1
Machine Learning                 3                    1                1
Statistics                       1                    2                2
```